# Modern Cell phone ringtones

Tags: effects, phone

Anyone know of a current library that caters to more smartphone tones? In a pinch and wish I had the time to work up my own.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Cleartones](http://cleartones.net)

OK, that's it for my self-promotion ;-)

- Oh wait, you want factory smartphone tones? Sorry, can't help you there.

Comment:   Aren't the tones for real phones copyrighted or protected by trademark (if it's part of the brand)? 

Comment: I know Apple's are.

Comment: You are allowed to use a phone's real ringtones/beeps.  ONLY if you use them in the exact context in which they actually occur for said device, and ONLY if it's blatantly obvious that the character is using said particular device (shown onscreen visibly etc).  I often opt to create my own tones from scratch though.

Comment: @Hugo regarding Cleartones, are they being sold/licensed as royalty free for sound editors to actually use them... or no? The site doesn't clarify as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Stavrosound You are right, I still have to add these terms to the site. They are sold as ringtones. If someone wants to use them for anything else (an app, or some kind of audio production), they can contact me to talk about a license. 